# SPLIT_BUNDLE 112: Policy Declaration - Data Safety Section: Location Data Type - Precise Location

Tags: declaration, policy

Recently, you rejected our updated "Data safety" declaration. However, in the email, it was stated that: SPLIT_BUNDLE 112: Policy Declaration - Data Safety Section: Location Data Type - Precise Location

We would like to inform you that our current working version used for clients is 145 (1.145.0). SPLIT_BUNDLE 112 is a version for closed testing, and we haven't been using it for a long time.

In the App bundle explorer, we can indeed see that version 112 is active. Versions 95, 108, and 112 are also active.

These versions are only used for internal closed testing and are not used for clients.

These versions are not up to date, as we previously requested Location data when it was allowed. Now we are experiencing an issue with deactivating old versions that prevent us from submitting the current "Data safety". Changes can only be submitted all at once.

My question. How can we deactivate versions 95, 108, and 112?

We tried to add new bundles for closed testing, but at the same time the changed policy and bundles are sent for consideration. The policy is rejected and so are the bundles